# Big, red-colored "Demo" text on the center of the tablet screen

Tags: screen

The word "Demo" is visible in the center of the screen in a big red font at all times. It is there even when you play games or go to Play Store. The tablet is not a floor model nor in demo mode.

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

How do I remove the "Demo" text from the device screen?

Comment: Could you get the screenshot and put the link here? Also, please mention your tablet model and Android version.

Comment: After further research ([1](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/448935-why-big-red-demo-my-screen-how-do-i-clear.html), [2](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/447716-how-do-i-remove-demo-mode.html)), some managed to solve this by upgrading the firmware/installing stock/custom ROM. However, we need more info to solve this specific issue.

Comment: I've updated the question with the screenshots and screenshot that gives info about the device.

Comment: Do you have a "trial version" theme or overlay to system?

Comment: well I don't know really...how would we check that?

Comment: One thing that I can see from the screenshot is the build number: polaris_eng 4.2.2 JDQ39 20140513 **test-keys**, so I'm assuming that it's using ROM for testing purpose. Unfortunately, there is not so much hint from all of these info, I couldn't find what brand it is for model C703, and whether if there is existing custom ROM. I'll try to research more, but don't count on me on this one.

Comment: It's a brand called I-touch...some Dubai company.Actually it's my cousin's.I do appreciate your effort :)

Comment: when you tap on the build number it says "No need,you are already a developer."

Comment: And I did try switching off developer mode and rebooting

Comment: I solved it myself :D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuftLiwzeeI

Comment: @Jose Could you please answer your own question and describe how you solved the issue? Of course you can include the Youtube link (though I don't know what's behind it, as I cannot access it – Youtube is blocked here). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Precaution: Trojan reported in this file by MalwareBytes Mobile (from [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92956/big-red-colored-demo-text-on-the-center-of-the-tablet-screen/93417#comment225542_93417)). Use at your own risk.

---

From [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuftLiwzeeI) posted on [Jose's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92956/there-is-a-word-demo-on-my-android-tab-right-on-the-center-in-big-red-font#comment116620_92956),

> 1. Turn on the device.
> 2. Connect to your PC by the USB.
> 3. Download SystemPack.apk (original: [MEGA](https://mega.co.nz/#!4AEjGCAb!Hh3VDhsVs6zXdxYcLgEFMntl_vd7Iz4vofYGBGE29ew), mirror: [MediaFire](https://www.mediafire.com/?5jh9hj7lhb8p3zv)).
> 4. Copy the .apk file to a directory on your device's memory.
> 5. On your device, look for the .apk file using the files manager and install it by touching on it and following the given instructions.
> 6. Shutdown your device, wait for 30 seconds, and the "DEMO" text will be gone.
>
> Notice that the .apk file is like a "patch", so if you reset your phone into factory settings, the "DEMO" text will appear again.

**Disclosure:** The MediaFire mirror was uploaded by original poster of the answer. The file was uploaded as-is, without any compromise.

Comment: If there is a better/safer place to upload Android-related file (which is, APK file), just add/update the link.

Comment: Trojan reported in this file by MalwareBytes Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Im have this trouble - when DISABLE apps: **com.clouds.server** in system.

When I enable this app - inscription disappeared.

Also.. You Maybe disable/delete: **com.android.server**

Reinstall/Enable this app - can help you.